# const * char in struct in class - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have this code and it gives me segmentation fault.

```
struct TRecord {
    const char * Id;
    const char * Name;
};
class CClass {
    CClass ();
    ~CClass ();
    bool Add ( const char * id, const char * name);
    TRecord ** m_record;
    int m_count;
};

CClass::CClass (void) {
    m_count = 0;
    m_record = new TRecord * [1000];
}

CClass::~CClass(void) {
    for(int i=0;i<m_count;i++){
        delete m_record[i];
    }
    delete [] m_record;
}

bool CClass::Add (const char * id, const char * name) {
    m_record[m_count] -> Id = new char[11];
    m_record[m_count] -> Name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];

    m_record[m_count] -> Id = id;
    m_record[m_count] -> Name = name;

    m_count++;
    return true;
}
```

If I add for example const char haha[2222]; to struct TRecord, it works. I don't understand why. Can you help me?

P.S. I can't use string.

Comment: Which method do you call on which object to produce a segmentation fault?

Comment: Is a complete minimal example too much to ask?

Comment: This line isn't valid C++: `m_record = new TRecord * [1000];`

Comment: @BrianNeal It's valid, It will allocate memory for thousands of `TRecord *`s to m_record.

Comment: @MostafaR oops, you are correct. The spaces around the * threw me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line as to top of you `Add` function declaration, It will fix your `Segmentation Fault` problem.

```
m_record[m_count] = new TRecord;
```

But as you can see in answers and comments, your code has many problems. Most important problem is that you have not any good plan for your garbage objects. So your code have memory leakage.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about this :/ Thanks!

Comment: @mostafaR what about the fact that he leaks memory every time he calls  `Add`?

Comment: @DanF I should fix my sentence, I think with this line the Segmentation Fault Error will be fixed, but It has problems yet.

Comment: @DanF Thanks, I tried to edit my answer and mention other problems of code in it.

Comment: How can I fix the problem with garbage objects? A destructor in struct?

Answer (score 1):

One error is that you are not following the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) in your CRegister class. That often causes segfaults.

Another error is that you do not initialise your m_record[i] pointers. So you destructor may call delete[] on garbage values.

A third error is that you apparently dereference the same garbage values in CRegister::Add.